# Confused with the return type (reference, const reference)

Tags: c++, reference

I mistakenly ended up writing following code.
It works on Windows (using VS2010) but not on Mac(GCC).

Can someone describe what is exactly happening on the return type here and why it doesn't work on Mac Release build.

```
const Mystruct* const & GetMyObject() const
{
    return m_pObject;
}
```

m_pObject is a pointer in this class allocated on heap.

Edited:
Above code compiles on Mac. But when I execute following statement it gives me a garbage pointer

```
Mystruct* pObjectTemp = const_cast<Mystruct*>(GetMyObject());
```

Comment: What error do you get on Mac?

Comment: please provide us with the compiler's output. what does it say exactly?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what's wrong, so we are unable to help you at all. You should also present the full [testcase](http://sscce.org) that you've been using during your hours of debugging so far.

Comment: As for why it doesn't work on Mac, try including the most trivial error information.

Comment: In general VS C is more liberal and tries to do what it thinks the user might want versus a stricter interpretation of standards as seen by gcc.

Comment: Er, this is clearly not C.

Comment: @Jim is correct (aside from stating the wrong language). My spidey senses detect a temporary bound to ref-to-non-`const` somewhere close in the OP's code.

Comment: It wouldn't work on Mac debug build either if that was the case.

Comment: @DeadMG: The OP did not say that it does.

Comment: True, but the specification of Release build does imply that.

Comment: "it gives me a garbage pointer" How do you know? What are you talking about?

Comment: @DeadMG: Partially, but the first line implies otherwise, so I choose to stick with the wider interpretation, especially as it makes more sense in this case.

Comment: You need a *complete* example that I can compile on my own machine. This extra information is not going to be of much use at all.

Answer (score 7):

It is a constant reference to a pointer to a constant Mystruct.

Comment: You only answered half the question; shame on you. Why it doesn't work on Mac Release build?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a constant-reference to a constant-pointer and then using `const_cast` to convert it to a raw pointer.  That conversion will not work:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

```
const Mystruct* pObjectTemp = t.GetMyObject();
```

That should return the same pointer you have in your instantiated `t` object (note that if t is on the stack, once it goes out of scope, the destructor should be cleaning up it's memory, meaning pObjectTemp will be pointing to memory that is no longer allocated).

You also should modify your function:

```
const Mystruct* const GetMyObject() const
{
    return m_pObject;
}
```

There is no real benefit to returning a pointer by reference in this case and changing it will prevent the problem Mike mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254260/529761).

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone describe what is exactly happening on the return type here

The return type is a reference to a constant pointer to a constant `Mystruct` object.

> and why it doesn't work on Mac Release build.

You forgot to show the declaration of `Mystruct`, but I'll guess that it's a member declared as:

```
Mystruct* m_pObject;
```

Note that there is no `const`, making it a different pointer type to the `const Mystruct*` that the function returns a reference to.

In that case, you're trying to return a reference to the wrong pointer type: `const Mystruct*` rather than `Mystruct*`. In order to return the correct type, the function must create a temporary pointer of type `const Mystruct*`. However, after returning a reference to the temporary, it goes out of scope and may be overwritten with garbage: using the return value gives undefined behaviour.

To fix it, return the pointer by value:

```
const Mystruct* GetMyObject() const {return m_pObject;}
```

You might also want a non-constant overload, to avoid the need for the dodgy casting:

```
Mystruct* GetMyObject() {return m_pObject;}
```

UPDATE:

To demonstrate that this is indeed the problem (assuming that I'm correct in guessing the type of `m_pObject`), consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Mystruct {};

struct Test {
    Test() : m_pObject(0) {}

    const Mystruct * const & GetMyObject() const {
        return m_pObject;
    }

    Mystruct * m_pObject;
};

int main() {
    Test test;

    std::cout << "MEMBER: " << &test.m_pObject << std::endl;
    std::cout << "RETURN: " << &test.GetMyObject() << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler identifies the problem:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In member function ‘const Mystruct* const& Test::GetMyObject() const’:
test.cpp:9:16: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]
```

and running it demonstrates that the returned reference does *not* refer to the member:

```
$ ./a.out 
MEMBER: 0x7fff7a3c4c20
RETURN: 0x7fff7a3c4c08
```

Comment: Incorrect.  A pointer is basically an integer (raw type).  Returning it as a constant simply means it is non-volatile (not a new object).  More specifically, the pointer itself is not put on the heap, but the stack.  So copying it's value (which points to memory on the heap) to another pointer on the stack does not move the heap object (nor does it create a new heap object).

Comment: @ZacHowland: Returning a *reference* to the wrong pointer type requires the creation of a temporary of the correct type. Pointer-to-constant and pointer-to-nonconstant are different types, so the function can't return a direct reference to the member. Instead, it creates a temporary pointer and returns a dangling reference to that. (As you say, returning it by value is fine, which is exactly why I suggested that as the solution).

Comment: @ZacHowland: I've added a demonstration that this is indeed what's happening.

Comment: It doesn't create a new pointer, it does an implicit cast (you can implicitly cast TO const, just not FROM it).  He can return by reference, but he has to have the correct type for his return value (or correctly cast it), which he isn't doing at present.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Of course it creates a new (temporary) pointer: the result of the implicit conversion is a temporary `const Mystruct*`, as the compiler warning clearly indicates. If it didn't, there'd be nothing to return a reference to. It *could* return a reference to the member, but *only* if the type matched - the result of any conversion would be a temporary. But you probably don't want to return a non-constant pointer from a constant function, and you probably don't want the member to be constant, so returning by value is probably a better option.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Unless you're suggesting `return reinterpret_cast<const Mystruct* const&>(p_mObject);` - but that would be revolting.

Comment: I agree that returning a pointer by value (especially a constant pointer) is a much better option (there is no real benefit to returning a pointer by reference) ... and I only use `reinterpret_cast` when absolutely necessary ... and after some whiskey.  However, I think I found the disconnect:  If you change the return like to `return const_cast<const Mystruct* const>(m_pObject);` both G++ and VS give the warning.  It would appear that VS's optimizations are masking it from picking up on that warning for implicit casts.

Answer (score 0):

VS decided to relax the interpretation of const and allowed a variable pointer to be returned.  Gcc, being stricter in type checking, did not.

As an aside, code that runs in gcc tends to run on VS, but the reverse is not necessarily the case.